# CSS image sprites

Tags: css

I'm using 4 separate images in my website, Now if I use image sprites to display those 4 images will it reduce the http request, if so I'm  wondering.

considering below example 1:(here 2 http requests are sent)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
 #home {
width: 46px;
height: 44px;
background: url(sevenwonders.gif) 0 0;//first http request
}

#next {
width: 43px;
height: 44px;
background: url(sevenwonders.gif) -91px 0; //second http request
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="home" src="something.gif"> 
<img id="next" src="something.gif">

</body>
</html>
```

considering below example 2 (2 http requests are sent)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <img id="home" src="tajmahal.gif">//first http request
 <img id="next" src="pisatower.gif">//second http request

 </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you so much for your precious time.

Comment: What is your question exactly? In the first example you would have only one HTTP request, as it's only one image but used twice with a background offset.

Comment: thank you@johnny kutnowski .anyhow I made two http request for a single image. this is my doubt

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer  @johnny kutnowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your code and using sample images to illustrate, the following proves you will do only one HTTP request per image, no matter if it's repeated.

Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
 #home {
width: 46px;
height: 44px;
background: url(http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg) 0 0;//first http request
}

#next {
width: 43px;
height: 44px;
background: url(http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg) -91px 0; //second http request
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="home" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Aurora_as_seen_by_IMAGE.PNG"> 
<img id="next" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">

</body>
</html>
```

This only returns 3 requests: 1 per image in the body and 1 for the CSS background image, used twice.

[image: Network tab on Chrome]

**There is however** the issue of misuse of markup and CSS in your code.
You should not set an `image-background` property to an `img` tag, which is an image by itself.

Choose a method and stick to it: either use images in your body (which will result in multiple images and therefore multiple requests) or use neutral elements like a `div` with specified `background-image` properties, using `background-position` to offset the sprite image.

Comment: Well explained. @Mari Selvan It depends on requirement of the design to choose the method. But the goal should be to load the pages fast and minimize the requests wherever possible . So using sprite wherever can is good thing. +1

Comment: @MariSelvan glad to help! If you think this solves your issues, please consider accepting my answer so future users may also benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wonder why do you choose to use `<img>` tag and attach a background image to it?
Secondly, each image src will be an http request (in css and in html tag), so using a sprite is surely a good idea when you choose to display the image as background image.
You might consider loading a 1px by 1px transparent gif to the src of the img tags to minimize the http load. (you can stretch it to the desired width and height)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure..
I just noticed I didn't replied on the http requests accurately... if you load the same image twice, only one http request will accure. @mari-selvan